# Integrate works but NIntegrate doesn't

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have a complicated integral function that I'm trying to evaluate, which will have to be done numerically. I wanted to try a simpler one first, one that has an analytic form, because I could check the answer.

The version `FT` I defined with `Integrate` works fine.

```
w0 = Sqrt[2*Pi*zR/(Pi*k)];
zR = 1;
k = 2*Pi/(532*10^-9);
w[z_] := Sqrt[w0^2*(1 + (z/zR)^2)]
f[x_, y_, z_] := Sqrt[2/Pi]*1/w[z]*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/(w[z]^2)]

FT[kx_, ky_, z_] := 
  1/(2*Pi)*Integrate[f[x, y, z]*Exp[-I*kx*x - I*ky*y], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}]
FT[1, 1, 1]
```

However, when I use `NIntegrate` in place of `Integrate`, I get an error and no answer.

```
FT[kx_, ky_, z_] :=  
  1/(2*Pi)*NIntegrate[f[x, y, z]*Exp[-I*kx*x - I*ky*y], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}]    
FT[1, 1, 1]
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: What error does it give?  (Include it in the question, so others searching the site with the same problem might benefit.)

Comment: The "problem" might be... read the docs? In any case, among many ways to resolve this, using `MinRecursion -> 5` in the `NIntegrate` and `Chop` on the result gets the same end result...

Comment: As noted by @ciao, `FT[kx_, ky_, z_] :=  1/(2*Pi)*NIntegrate[   f[x, y, z] *Exp[-I*kx*x - I*ky*y], {x, -Infinity,  Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, MinRecursion -> 4] // Chop` gives the same numerical value as the symbolic solution, `0.00023217`.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your second definition of `FT` to

```
FT[kx_, ky_, z_] := 
  1/(2*Pi)*
    NIntegrate[
      f[x, y, z]*Exp[-I*kx*x - I*ky*y], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, 
      MinRecursion -> 4] // Chop
```

solves your problem.